# How would I dynamically fill an array with all functions with a specific prefix?

Tags: python

So I have 3 functions defined. I currently put all those functions in an array and call one randomly as so:

```
import random

def testFunc01():
    print("testFunc01")

def testFunc02():
    print("testFunc02")
    
def testFunc03():
    print("testFunc03")

functionList = [testFunc01, testFunc02, testFunc03]

def randFunction():
    functionList[random.randint(0,len(functionList))-1]()
    
randFunction()
```

Now, I want to dynamically fill the array functionList with all functions with the same prefix (in this case, test, but assume my real code has a more thoroughly unique prefix)

I've looked at the dir() function but I'm really not proficient enough to find a way to parse those results and put the matching functions back into an array. I'm curious to see how it could be done.

Comment: You should put the functions in a dictionary if the name of the function is significant. Then you can filter the dict for specific keys.

Comment: Yes this smells XY problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `globals`:

```py
def test_one():
    print("testOne")

def test_two(value):
    print(f"testTwo with {value}")

def dont_test_this():
    print("not testing")

def dont_test_this_too(value):
    print(f"not testing this with {value}")

def test():
    print("the test")

def find_functions(prefix):
    return {k: v for k, v in globals().items() if k.startswith(prefix)}

print(find_functions("test"))
# Output:
# {'test_one': <function test_one at 0x00DA7778>, 'test_two': <function test_two at 0x01979EC8>, 'test': <function test at 0x01979DF0>}

print(find_functions("dont"))
# Output:
# {'dont_test_this': <function dont_test_this at 0x01609E80>, 'dont_test_this_too': <function dont_test_this_too at 0x01609E38>}

find_functions("test")["test_one"]()
# Output:
# testOne
```

To have a list of functions, you can use instead:

```py
def find_functions(prefix):
    return [v for k, v in globals().items() if k.startswith(prefix)]
```